# jQuery load(URL) not working when loading page-fragments?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this page, the first button is working good.

I want when press the second button to give me the link that is in the href, i tried like this , but i got the whole page , not just the value of the link , why please?

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

      var url = "http://localhost/test/asdfasdf.php";

      $("#button").on("click", function() {
        $('body').load( url  );
       });

      $("#button2").on('click',function(){
        $('body').load( url +"#link" );
      });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" id="button" value="load" />
  <input type="button" id="button2" value="search for a tag" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. **If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.**"

Comment: Why don't you post the content of `asdfasdf.php` that way it can be a bit clearer what you are trying to do.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your code evaluates to `.load('http://localhost/test/asdfasdf.php#link')`, where `#link` is a useless fragment.  You need a space to engender jQuery's special behavior of automatic DOM parsing and element loading.

```
$("body").load(url + " #link");
```

EDIT: to get the actual link value:

```
$.get(url).done(function (html) {
    console.log($(html).find('#link').attr('href'));
});
```

You can also append to `body` inside of the `.done` callback.

Comment: i want the value of href, the space gives me the 'click' word, i want the value of href please

Comment: Try `$("body").load(url + " #link", function () { alert($("body").find('#link').attr('href')); });`

Comment: you are the GOD, it works :) it alter :) how could i just put it in the body not alter it, taaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaank you

Answer (score 4):

I think you want a space:

```
$('body').load(url + " #link");
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

All you seem to want is the `href` of the `a#link` element at that URL. So instead of loading it into the `<body>`, just make the AJAX request, and look through the result:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost/test/asdfasdf.php",
    dataType: "html"
}).done(function (data) {
    var the_link = $(data).find("#link");
    alert(the_link.attr("href"));
});
```

And to put the `href` in the `<body>`, add this line in the `.done()` method:

```
$("body").html(the_link.attr("href"));
// or
$("body").append(the_link.attr("href"));
```

But if you actually want to load the `a#link` element into `<body>`, do what you had before, but then look for the `a#link` element and get its attribute:

```
$('body').load(url + " #link", function () {
    var the_link = $("#link");
    alert(the_link.attr("href"));
});
```

Comment: your way give me the data inside the <a> i want the value of href, +1 to you

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli You should provide a little more info of what exactly is returned. Is something like this returned? `<a href="whatever" id="link">Link</a>` And all you want is `"whatever"`?

Comment: it gives me the words inside the <a> like `<a> LOVE </a> ` , i got the LOVE word

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Is that all you want (the href)? Like do you actually want the `<a>` to be put in the `<body>`? Or do you just want to get the `href` from that `<a>` from that URL?

Comment: i want to put the href value in the body

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

You're trying to capture the href of the `<a>` on a different page. A try:

```
$.get(url+' #link', function(data) {
    var $link = $(data).find('a').attr('href');
    alert($link);
});
```

That is my very best guess, but its a shot in the dark.

Comment: is there anything inside of the element with id #link on the page u specified?

Comment: yes there is the <a> and i want the href of that a, not the data inside the <a></a>

Comment: you want to capture the href of the <a> element on a different page? you shouldnt be using `.load` at all then.

Comment: i gave my best shot in my edited answer. not tested whatsoever, but some modification on that should give you what you want.

Comment: haha bloody hell i just saw someone tried the same thing. at least i get some consolation in that my theory worked!

Comment: thank u for your help , i will upvote to alllllllllllllll ur answers in all questions :)